# Can someone tell me why my github.io is not updating?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm working on making a github page. I'm a beginner with github, but when I go to https://montanabraswell.github.io/example/ it shows the general bootstrap I'm trying to modify. I already made changes in Atom and when I open the index using chrome, the updates are fine and I made sure github is synced. I waited over 10 minutes but no changes have been made. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: How would we know?

Comment: Have you pushed to origin? Have you cleared your browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

Did you push the changes to gh-pages?

If not you are not updating the version on your GitHub repository.

Anyway, I highly recommend using [npm package gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) it makes things much easier for you.

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

and in your `package.json`

```
"publish": "gh-pages -d  YOUR_BUILD_FOLDER"
```